# Wrap posts from a category in HTML

Tags: posts, categories, html

I want to get multiple posts content from a particular category. I would also like to wrap each post around some HTML. Any ideas on how to best do this?

Comment: Have you done any research on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `WP_Query`. You can pass array as parameter. The array can contain category, number of posts, order etc. Then you can use the while loop to display posts and wrap them in html.

Please go to http://wordpress.org and look for `WP_Query` for further details.